# Setting state for Google Maps using map type, selected marker, and zoom level loaded from local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am customizing the WordPress Geodirectory plugin's Google Maps API functionality to store the user set/selected map type, marker, and zoom level in local storage.

I have the user set map type and zoom level functionality working, but am struggling with implementing the selected map marker.

How would I go about storing and retrieving the selected map marker from local storage and displaying it on the map when the user clicks/taps back in the browser?

My existing custom code is included below:

```
const zoomChangeListener = google.maps.event.addListener(jQuery.goMap.map, 'zoom_changed', function (event) {
  storeUserZoom();
});

loadUserZoom();

function storeUserZoom() {
  let zoom = jQuery.goMap.map.getZoom();
  localStorage.setItem( 'zoom', zoom);
  // console.log('Storing zoom level: ' + zoom);
}

function loadUserZoom() {
  let zoom = localStorage.getItem( 'zoom' );
  if (localStorage.getItem( 'zoom' )) {
    jQuery.goMap.map.setZoom(parseInt(zoom));
    // console.log('Local storage zoom level: ' + zoom);
  }
}

const mapTypeChangeListener = google.maps.event.addListener(jQuery.goMap.map, 'maptypeid_changed', function (event) {
  storeUserMapType();
});

loadUserMapType();

function storeUserMapType() {
  let mapType = jQuery.goMap.map.getMapTypeId();
  localStorage.setItem( 'maptype', mapType);
  // console.log('Map type changed: ' + mapType);
}

function loadUserMapType() {
  let mapType = localStorage.getItem( 'maptype' );
  if (localStorage.getItem( 'maptype' )) {
    jQuery.goMap.map.setMapTypeId(mapType);
    // console.log('Loading map type: ' + mapType);
  }
}

function storeUserMarker(item, map_canvas) {
  let markerId, markerTitle, markerIcon, markerPosition;
  markerId = item.id;
  markerTitle = item.title;
  markerIcon = item.icon = {
    url: item.icon,
    // scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(resizeW, resizeH),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
  };
  // markerIcon = item.icon;
  // console.log(markerIcon);
  markerPosition = item.position;
  localStorage.setItem( 'id', markerId );
  localStorage.setItem( 'title', markerTitle );
  localStorage.setItem( 'icon', JSON.stringify(markerIcon) );
  localStorage.setItem( 'position', JSON.stringify(markerPosition));
}

function loadUserMarker(item, map_canvas) {
  let markerId = localStorage.getItem( 'id' );
  let markerTitle = localStorage.getItem( 'title' );
  let markerIcon = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( 'icon' ));
  let markerPosition = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( 'position'   ));
  if (localStorage.getItem( 'position' )) {
    let marker = {
      id: markerId,
      title: markerTitle,
      icon: markerIcon,
      position: markerPosition,
      visible: true,
      clickable: true
    };
    gd_infowindow.open(jQuery.goMap.map, marker);
  }
}
```

**Geodirectory initMap function simplified with my additions marked as custom code**

```
function initMap(map_options, marker) {
  /** Custom code begin **/
  google.maps.event.addListener(jQuery.goMap.map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    loadUserMarker(marker);
  });
  /** Custom code end **/
}
```

**Geodirectory create_marker function with my additions marked as custom code**

```
// create the marker and set up the event window
function create_marker(item, map_canvas) {
  if (window.gdMaps == 'osm') {
    return create_marker_osm(item, map_canvas);
  }
  var map_options = eval(map_canvas);
  jQuery("#" + map_canvas).goMap();
  gd_infowindow = (typeof google !== 'undefined' && typeof google.maps !== 'undefined') ? new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 200
  }) : null;
  if (item.lt && item.ln) {
    var marker_id, title, icon, cs;
    marker_id = item['m'];
    title = geodir_htmlEscape(item['t']);
    cs = item['cs'];
    icon = item['icon'] ? item['icon'] : geodir_params.default_marker_icon;
    iconW = item['w'] ? parseFloat(item['w']) : 0;
    iconH = item['h'] ? parseFloat(item['h']) : 0;
    iconMW = geodir_params.marker_max_width ? parseFloat(geodir_params.marker_max_width) : 0;
    iconMH = geodir_params.marker_max_height ? parseFloat(geodir_params.marker_max_height) : 0;
    /* Some svg files has dimensions with different unit */
    if (geodir_params.resize_marker && ( iconW < iconMW || iconH < iconMH ) && icon.substr((icon.lastIndexOf('.')+1)).toLowerCase() == 'svg') {
        iconW = iconW * 10;
        iconH = iconH * 10;
    }
    if (geodir_params.resize_marker && iconW > 5 && iconH > 5 && ((iconMW > 5 && iconW > iconMW) || (iconMH > 5 && iconH > iconMH))) {
        resizeW = iconW;
        resizeH = iconH;
        resize = false;

        if (iconMH > 5 && resizeH > iconMH) {
            _resizeH = iconMH;
            _resizeW = Math.round(((_resizeH * resizeW) / resizeH) * 10) / 10;

            resizeW = _resizeW;
            resizeH = _resizeH;
            resize = true;
        }

        if (iconMW > 5 && resizeW > iconMW) {
            _resizeW = iconMW;
            _resizeH = Math.round(((_resizeW * resizeH) / resizeW) * 10) / 10;

            resizeW = _resizeW;
            resizeH = _resizeH;
            resize = true;
        }
        if (resize && resizeW > 5 && resizeH > 5) {
            icon = {
                url: icon,
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(resizeW, resizeH),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point((Math.round(resizeW / 2)), resizeH)
            };
        }
    }
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.lt, item.ln);
    var marker = jQuery.goMap.createMarker({
        id: marker_id,
        title: title,
        position: latlng,
        visible: true,
        clickable: true,
        icon: icon,
        label: cs,
        zIndex: (item.zIndex ? item.zIndex : 0),
        zIndexOrg: (item.zIndexOrg ? item.zIndexOrg : 0)
    });
    bounds.extend(latlng);
    // Adding a click event to the marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'spider_click', function() { // 'click' => normal, 'spider_click' => Overlapping Marker Spiderfier
        /** Custom code begin **/
        storeUserMarker(marker);
        /** Custom code end **/
        var marker_url = map_options.map_marker_ajax_url;
        is_zooming = true;
        jQuery("#" + map_canvas).goMap();
        var preview_query_str = '';
        if (item.post_preview) {
            preview_query_str = '&post_preview=' + item.post_preview;
        }
        marker_url = marker_url + '' + item.m;
        post_data = marker_url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&';
        post_data += '_wpnonce=' + map_options._wpnonce;
        if (map_options.bubble_size) {
            post_data += '&small=1';
        }
        if (map_options.map_marker_url_params) {
            post_data += map_options.map_marker_url_params;
        }
        var loading = '<div id="map_loading"></div>';
        gd_infowindow.open(jQuery.goMap.map, marker);
        gd_infowindow.setContent(loading);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: marker_url + post_data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(xhr, error) {
                alert(error);
            },
            success: function(response) {
                jQuery("#" + map_canvas).goMap();
                html = typeof response == 'object' && response.html ? geodir_htmlEscape(response.html) : '';
                gd_infowindow.setContent(html);
                gd_infowindow.open(jQuery.goMap.map, marker);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery(document.body).trigger('geodir_map_infowindow_open', [{
                        map: 'google',
                        canvas: map_canvas,
                        content: html
                    }]);
                }, 100);
                // give the map 1 second to reposition before allowing it to reload
                setTimeout(function() {
                    is_zooming = false;
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
        return;
    });
    // Overlapping Marker Spiderfier
    jQuery.goMap.oms.addMarker(marker);
    // Adding a visible_changed event to the marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'visible_changed', function() {
        gd_infowindow.close(jQuery.goMap.map, marker);
    });
    return true;
  } else {
    //no lat & long, return no marker
    return false;
  }
}
```

The `loadUserMarker();` function returns [object Object] in the console when executed.

The functionality can be tested on the [staging site](https://staging.callkneehill.ca/visitors/). Try clicking on a map marker, visiting the individual page, then return to the map with the browser back button.

**Update**

I am receiving the following error when trying to load the previously clicked/tapped map marker: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: b.anchor.get is not a function`. I know it relates to anchoring the info window to the map marker, but I am not sure how to correct it.

My `storeUserMarker` function has been updated to make `item.icon` into an object that includes the marker URL, origin, and anchor.

How would I go about getting the marker's anchor data so the info window can be displayed?

Comment: in `storeUserMarker` you obviously have access to the marker object. why dont you save that marker in storage and trigger a click on it?

Comment: @Alex The clicked marker's ID and position (lat and lng) are being stored in local storage. I am struggling with having the marker's ID and position with info window loaded when the user returns to Visitors map page. My `loadUserMarker` function brings that data, I just don't know how to apply it to the selected marker on the map.

Comment: why dont you just store the marker itself and if the user goes back and localstorage has it stored, do a `marker.click()`?

Comment: @Alex I have updated my original question with new and updated code, and my progress. The following error is being displayed: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: b.anchor.get is not a function`.